# How to get daily and hourly average?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, average

I have a contact table with a start date and start hour and I want to get the average of how many contacts I got by the weekday and hour for a large date range.

What I have now is a pivot table with the count like this for a single month.

| Weekday | 12AM | 1AM | 2AM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | 10 | 14 | 32 |
| Monday | 12 | 18 | 21 |

How can I achieve the average of the contacts in the same way presented, i.e average of contacts on the Sundays 12AM for the last 3 months.

Currently I'm doing manually, but as the data grows it takes more and more time to update.

Comment: Check out averageif() or averageifs().

Comment: I don't understand your question. Average what, exactly?

Comment: *" I want to get the average of how many contacts I got by the weekday and hour "*

Comment: @SolarMike - averageifs doesn't seem to function that well when 'array to condition upon' is itself a function (e.g. averageifs(avg_range, weekday(range,2), #) - so this approach may require an interim calc (but I may be mistaken/doing something wrong!).  Workaround otherwise: see proposal below/ use average(avg. range * condition 1 *... * condition2); alternatively sum(1*(condition 1)*(condition2)) hasn't let me down yet! ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9-EHaYjaf1sOC1Pym?e=Pb1Hoe)/screenshots refer:

**Method 1** (general purpose/Excel version)

[image: Method 1]

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF(1*(WEEKDAY($B$4:$B$78,2)=$G3)*$C$4:$C$78*24=H$2),$D$4:$D$78,"")),"")
```

**Method 2** (Office 360 compatible Excel version)

[image: Method 2 - 360 version]

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER($D$4:$D$78,1*(WEEKDAY($B$4:$B$78,2)=$G3)*($C$4:$C$78*24=H$2))),"")
```